# float value always return as 1 after assigning in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am storing float value in UserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.labelSlider.lowerValue] forKey:@"KEYSLIDERLOWERVALUE"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

but when I fetch value in variable "lowerVal", proper value assign to float variable but when I am going to assign float "lowerVal" to self.lableSlider.lowerValue it always give me 1.

```
float lowerVal = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"KEYSLIDERLOWERVALUE"] floatValue];

if (lowerVal > [[self.arrPriceRange valueForKey:@"minPrice"] floatValue]) {
        self.labelSlider.lowerValue = lowerVal;
    }else{
        self.labelSlider.lowerValue = [[self.arrPriceRange valueForKey:@"minPrice"] floatValue];
    }
```

in short when I print lowerVal in console it gives me 4.55(correct value) but when I print self.lableSlider.lowerValue it gives me 1.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `lowerVal > [[self.arrPriceRange valueForKey:@"minPrice"] floatValue]` is true?

Comment: @trick14: Yes.when I debug it my condition goes to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

**Setting Default Values**

```
-(void) saveFloatValue:(float)x forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setFloat:x forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

**Getting Default Values**

```
-(float) retrieveFloatValueWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults floatForKey:key];
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setFloat:forKey:

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NMRangeSlider? I've checked the source code and found:

```
- (void) setLowerValue:(float)lowerValue
{
    float value = lowerValue;

    if(_stepValueInternal>0)
    {
        value = roundf(value / _stepValueInternal) * _stepValueInternal;
    }

    value = MIN(value, _maximumValue);
    value = MAX(value, _minimumValue);

    if (!isnan(_lowerMaximumValue)) {
        value = MIN(value, _lowerMaximumValue);
    }

    value = MIN(value, _upperValue - _minimumRange);

    _lowerValue = value;

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Take care of these lines:

```
value = MIN(value, _maximumValue);
value = MAX(value, _minimumValue);
```

The default value of _maximumValue is 1.0, so lowerValue can not exceed it.
In this case, you should set maximumValue and minimumValue due to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong methods to access values in `NSUserDefaults`. Exchange

- `valueForKey:` with `objectForKey:`
- `setValue:forKey:` with `setObject:forKey:`

In your case you could also use the specialized methods for floating point types, which do the boxing/unboxing for you:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:self.labelSlider.lowerValue forKey:@"KEYSLIDERLOWERVALUE"];

float lowerVal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"KEYSLIDERLOWERVALUE"];
```

As a sidenote: calling `synchronize` is not necessary and just a waste of resources.

The methods you've been using (`valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`) are KVC accessors that are not expected or documented to work in `NSUserDefaults`.